# Is there any info regarding Elsa workflows compatibility?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8, elsa-workflows

So I was wondering if anyone knows if elsa workflows is compatible with .net framework 4.8 or is it just for the .net core?

I searched their documentation for this, however no sign for compatibility info over the documentation or the internet, what's found only mentions .net core and .net standard and no signs for .net framework versions 4.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [Readme](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core#elsa-workflows)

> Elsa Core is a workflows library that enables workflow execution in any .NET Core application.

To make it more clear you should know that Elsa core is based on `.NET Standard 2.1` which is not supported by `.NET Framework` as you can see in the table below (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-1#select-net-standard-version)).

[image: .netstandard2.1 implementations]

So you cannot use the current version of Elsa workflows with the .net framework 4.8.